# Extract a value of a certain row based on a particular value in a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to R and am working on a lingituinal data. What I'd like to do with dplyr, is to extract a value of certain row by matching the value of another column.

I tried using which() within mutute, but it doesn't work. Tried using indexes, but it has its own problems (as will shown below).

For example, suppose I have:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
             year = c(2013,2014,2015,2013,2015,2013,2014,2015,2013,2015),
             Income = c(49, 32, 47, 14, 15, 14, 46, 45, 16, 42),
             Sales = c(12, 21, 42, 30, 10, 19, 16, 27, 18, 32))
```

Eventually, I want to deduct values for a certain from prior year. For example, (Income in 2014) - (Income in 2013). What I want to do is to use dplyr in a similar way I call `df$Income[df$year=="2014"]` in base R.

The reason I don't go with:

```
dftemp <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Income14minus13 = Income[2] - Income[1])
```

is that indices don't account for the missin 2014s in the data, so I want to make sure I'm extracting exact values.

I've also tried this without success:

```
dftemp <- df %>%
enter code here`group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(Income13 = Income[which(year==2013)],
         Income14 = Income[which(year==2014)],
         Income14minus13 = Income14 - Income13)
```

Finally, I'd like to have this as an out put:

```
> desired_data
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      ID  year Income Sales Income13 Income14 Income15
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1  2013     49    12       49       32       47
 2     1  2014     32    21       49       32       47
 3     1  2015     47    42       49       32       47
 4     2  2013     14    30       14       NA       15
 5     2  2015     15    10       14       NA       15
 6     3  2013     14    19       14       46       45
 7     3  2014     46    16       14       46       45
 8     3  2015     45    27       16       46       45
 9     4  2013     16    18       16       NA       42
10     4  2015     42    32       16       NA       42
```

I've noticed that case-when() only produces the variable in a single row, thus not allowing for rowwise operations, whereas my desired output does so.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a join would help here?

```
df %>%
  left_join(by = "ID",
            df %>%
              select(ID, year, Income) %>%
              mutate(year = paste0("Income", year)) %>%
              tidyr::spread(year, Income)
  )

# A tibble: 10 x 7
      ID  year Income Sales Income2013 Income2014 Income2015
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1  2013     49    12         49         32         47
 2     1  2014     32    21         49         32         47
 3     1  2015     47    42         49         32         47
 4     2  2013     14    30         14         NA         15
 5     2  2015     15    10         14         NA         15
 6     3  2013     14    19         14         46         45
 7     3  2014     46    16         14         46         45
 8     3  2015     45    27         14         46         45
 9     4  2013     16    18         16         NA         42
10     4  2015     42    32         16         NA         42
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an alternative approach could be to reshape data from long to wide; missing values will then automatically become `NA` (or you can specify a value with `fill`).

For example

```
df %>%
    select(-Sales) %>%
    spread(year, Income) %>%
    mutate(Income14minus13 = `2014` - `2013`)
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#     ID `2013` `2014` `2015` Income14minus13
#  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>
#1     1     49     32     47             -17
#2     2     14     NA     15              NA
#3     3     14     46     45              32
#4     4     16     NA     42              NA
```